# ubuntu 19.04 and mysql 8.0.15. Cannot upgrade to 8.0.17

Tags: mysql, 19.04

I have installed ubuntu 19.04 with mysql 8.0.15

I would like to upgrade mysql to 8.0.17 but for same reason it keeps on saying I already have the lastest version.

I followed this procedure:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/

but after apt-get update the version prompted is 8.0.15

Any idea? 
Thank you!

Comment: Is the new version officially in the official repo your using? Do a search with `apt search mysql` and see if it's included in the results

Comment: Did you do this: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config`, To see what versions are available to you?

Comment: Hello! "apt search mysql" returns 8.0.15 and "sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config" just ask me to choose the main version ...

Comment: so it's not available to you as you can see from your search!

Comment: Ok i undertand that but I do not understand why. How can I make it available? On windows has been available for a while now and even on mysql website it says it's available. Even mysql 8.0.16 has been released on April

Comment: please give me the link to that information on the availability as it might be on another ubuntu version

Comment: On windows I installed it almost one month ago. Here are the release dates. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-17.html

Comment: and here is the download link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: It lists these versions `Ubuntu 16.04, 17.10, and 18.04` so yours isn't supported! But you could always use the docker image

Comment: it's strange because I had 18.04 and it was not appearing. That is why I updated to 19.04, i thought it could change something..

Comment: Next time don't update your system simply for one app use a container instead!

Comment: do you have a guide regarding how to update using the docker image? I have never tried it

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/linux-installation-docker.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the contents of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list`.

It should have a line with the contents (disco being the codename for Ubuntu 19.04):

```
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ disco mysql-8.0
```

You can also run the command `apt-cache policy mysql-server` to see which versions are available from where.

Comment: hello, thank you for answering. mysql.list content is this: deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ cosmic mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ cosmic mysql-8.0
deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ cosmic mysql-8.0

Comment: so the line you mentiones is missing. Why is it missing? do I just add it? also apt-cache policy mysql-server returns 8.0.15

Comment: I thought that file would automatically create when using dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config. But I did that some days ago so why didn't it update? what is the best way to fix it?

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in mysql-apt-config (which is my bad, since I wrote it). I assume you at one point installed it, then upgraded your system from Ubuntu 18.10 (which has the codename cosmic)? Simplest fix is probably to run apt-get purge mysql-apt-config, then reinstall it.

Comment: You could also just replace cosmic with disco in the file, but then the config package would probably just overwrite it again later.

Comment: thank you so much I will let you know!

Comment: it worked thank you!!!